# CSS a:focus "forget" last position if i click inside iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css

The `a:focus` on my CSS are working good, but only if i don't click on the `iframe` or in other place of the page.
How to avoid the `a:focus` loss last position, whatever where i click?

It's possible only with CSS or simple JavaScript?

While i navigate on SideNav it's working good:

[image]

If i click in other place of page, SideNav lost the last position:

[image]

My CSS and HTML

```
ul.SideNav_Main li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #2e849e;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    display: block;
}
 
ul.SideNav_Main li a:focus { background-color: #ffdb99;}
```

```
<li>

    <a href="#" onclick="Toggle_Visibility('T301');">Segurança</a>

    <ul class="SideNav_Sub" id="T301" style="display: block;">
        <li><a href="PasswordUpdate.php" target="_iframe">Change Password</a></li>    
        <li><a href="eKeyUpdate.php" target="_iframe">Change eKey</a></li>  
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="Logout.php" target="_parent">Logout</a></li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest is to use javascript (if you are interested in solving the problem using pure css, you can look into radio inputs). Add "mySidebarLinks" class to your links 
css:

```
  .myStyle{color: red;}
```

javascript:

```
  const links = document.getElementsByClassName("mySidebarLinks");

  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        for (var j = 0; j < links.length; j++) {
            if (links[j]!=e.target){
                links[j].classList.remove('myStyle');
            }else links[j].classList.add('myStyle');
        }
    });
  }
```

Comment: thank you. Working, but when i click on the first time, nothing happens, i need to click two times. BR

Comment: For me it seems to be working on the first click. Where have you defined the javascript? You should have it somewhere where it is initialized on site-load. Not in an onclick event nor something similar.

Comment: Already fixed. Not your problema. TY Again